# Problem regarding tkz-euclide and tkz-fct

Tags: pdftex, tkz-euclide, tkz-fct

first of all I apologize in advance for any grammar or spelling mistakes as English is a second language to me. If I'm not clear, don't hesitate to ask for details.

For context, I'm a fairly new LaTeX user (I used it 15 years ago durong my studies and decided to get back to it a month ago so it's safe to say I'm a beginner). I use MikTeX (it's up to date, I don't know the version) and TeXstudio (similarly up to date).
Up until now, I knew it was possible to draw some geometric shapes with LaTeX but I didn't know which tool to use. A friend of mine introduced me to tkz-euclide and I quickly managed to draw what I wanted.

The problem began when I decided that I wanted to plot functions. I installed gnuplot and followed a tutorial for creating environment variables in windows and then I configured TeXstudio with the path I had created (I hope that's clear).
And when I tried the first example in the documentation of tkz-fct, it failed and I got some errors, notably that "tkz-base should load before tkz-euclide" (but that was the case).
After some tries, I had only the axis and the grid but no function. I decided to continue writing another document and to my great surprise, tkz-euclide doesn't work anymore... and I got the same error.
I tried cancelling what I've done earlier by configuring TeXstudio the way it was (I had copied and pasted everything in a text document) and now the error is : "Erreur : impossible de lancer la commande pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_tPmCHo".tex" which means in English : "Error : impossible to launch pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_tPmCHo".tex"

I got this error for this simple construction here :

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/G,4/0/N,4/3/V}
    \tkzDrawPoints(G,N,V)
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](G){$G$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](N){$N$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](V){$V$} 
    \draw (G) -- node[below]{4 cm}(N) -- node[right]{3 cm}(V) -- node[sloped, above]{5 cm}(G);          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to continue working and I need to be able to at least use tkz-euclide (tkz-fct would be a nice bonus but I can manage without it). Any idea how to revert to a working tkz-euclide ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE.  Your clear example works with no error on my system, so it must be something at your end.  From the message, it appears to be trying to load a temporary file that no longer exists.  How can it do this?  Well it might be something in the `.aux` file that gets written automatically, and read back in on the second pass through the main file.  Try deleting any `*.aux` files in your working directory?

Comment: I deleted the only .aux file in the folder where the .tex is and there is no change.
Maybe I'll try to reinstall TeXstudio...

Comment: No problem for me with the last version of tkz-base and tkz-euclide. You don't need the line `\usepackage{tikz}` because `tkz` loads `tikz`.

Comment: OK, I think I understood what happened.
I tried to use pdflatex directly via cmd and it worked. So, I think the problem is the configuration of TeXstudio concerning pdflatex. It seems TeXstudio doesn't find pdflatex...

So, now I'll try to find what's wrong with TeXstudio... Thanks for your ansswer everyone, and if anyone knows where to look, well... I'd like to know too ^^;